# How to open iCloud CDT file

Tags: plist, icloud, eclipse-cdt

I found [this site](http://mentalfaculty.tumblr.com/post/23231176783/under-the-sheets-with-icloud-and-core-data-how-it) which details iCloud a bit more, on it, it talks about .CDT files and how they can be 'unzipped' and read as a .plist. As I am having issues with iCloud I thought I could at least see what was in them and see what exactly is being uploaded.

However, when right-clicking on the .CDT files there is no option to unzip them, nor do they open in Xcode.

Thanks for any replies!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're zip files all right, but the cdt extension makes Mac OS X think they're something else. You can either

- Copy them somewhere and change the "cdt" extension to "zip", or
- Unzip them at the command line, using "unzip".

They contain a binary property list file named "contents".

Comment: then use plutil to convert the plist to xml: plutil -convert xml1 contents*